# How to update datagridview in background

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows, datagridview

I have a class storing data collected from usb. I read the data regularly using a thread in background, sleep for 10ms and then repeat.

The data is bound into a datagridview _mydatagrid using List(of T) class. I do not use BindingList(Of T) because that will update the datagrid very frequently and will consume a lot of CPU resource.

To update the datagrid, I used two mechanisms:

- If the size of data is growing:

  _mydatagrid.DataSource = Nothing

  _mydatagrid.DataSource = (the instance of my storing data class)
- If the size of data has reach the limit that I want to store:

  _mydatagrid.Invalidate()

The code works fine, with little CPU usage as I intended. But one thing bothering me is that when the datagridview updated, it tends to get focus into it. So if I open another application, especially application with many windows forms, the datagridview is kind of fighting with the other application to get focus into it when it is doing the update. Hence it flicks a lot, and seems aggressive and not user friendly.

Is there a way to update the datagridview silently. I've try to do it in background, but I noticed that even so, when the `_mydatagridview.Invalidate()` or `_mydatagridview.Refresh()` is called, it will get focus regardless.

Any advice?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "Gets focus"? Does focus actually move from other controls to the datagridview or the form with the datagridview is activating, or are you just suggesting it draws the eyes because it flickers?

Answer (score 0):

The flickering is likely caused by setting the datasource to nothing and then setting it to something new. DataGridViews normally draw themselves row by row and it can be distracting.

I like to use a custom datagridview class that enables double buffering to avoid flickering. You also don't have to set the datasource to nothing, you can change it directly to the new source, and you don't have to call invalidate; setting the data source will cause the grid to redraw already.

```
Public Class CustomDataGridView
  Inherits DataGridView

  Public Sub New()
    Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, True)
    Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, True)
  End Sub
End Class
```

I don't know what you mean by "Gets Focus" though, none of the things you mentioned should cause it to steal focus, so this likely won't solve your focus issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What I meant with "get focus" is that when I load a another application, it will try to hold the control focus on it and prevent the other application to load forms. I can see that clearly if the application has many forms to load. If I minimize it then the other application will be loaded fine without "fighting" with the datagridview.

Comment: Will try the method you suggested to see if it makes a difference. Thanks.